# Covarience and correlation between conditioned and non-conditioned random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I have a problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathcal L^{2}$, and put $Y' = E(Y |X)$. Show that:

1. $Cov(Y, X) = Cov(Y', X)$
2. $Corr(Y, X) ≤ Corr(Y' , X)$

I have tried to solve 1 it by deriving the definition of covarience:

$E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(XY')-E(X)E(Y')$

and implacing $Y' = E(Y|X) = \int Y *f_{Y|X}dy$, but can't see the further way.

Also, to solve 2, it's just needed to proove, that $\sigma _{Y} > \sigma _{Y'} $, which is intuativly understandble, but i can't show it neither.

Comment: If you can apply the law of total expectation and variance directly, then it will solve your question 1 and 2 respectively with ease.

Comment: @BGM Could you please give a clue how to apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are down the correct path. You just have to compute the $E(Y^{'})$ realizing that it is a function of $X$,
$$
E(Y^{'}) = \int Y^{'} f_x(x) dx = \int y \ f_{y|x}(y|x) \ f_x(x) \ dx dy = \int y \ f_{x,y}(x,y) \ dx dy = E(Y)
$$
Which follows from the definition of conditional pdf. An alternate approach is to directly use the law of total expectation:
$$
E(Y) = E ( E(Y|X) ) = E (Y')
$$
Follow the same approach on the variance. Follow the same approach on $E(Y' \ X)$ to get that $E(Y'X) = E(YX)$. 
For the second part we apply the law of total variance:
$$
Var(Y) = E ( Var(Y|X) ) + Var( E(Y|X) ) = E ( Var(Y|X) ) + Var( Y' ) > Var( Y' )
$$
Since $ E ( Var(Y|X) )>0$.

Comment: Sorry, but this is unclear to me:
$ E(Y^{'}) = \int Y^{'} f_x(x) dx $

Comment: $Y'$ is a function of $X$, right? Then you can compute any $E(g(x))$ as $E(g(x))= \int g(x) f_x(x) dx$ from the definition of expectation. After that you just substitute from the definition of $Y'$.

Comment: Anyway, i can use the law of total expactation. 
But here's the part that i'am stucked at the moment:
$E(Y'X) = E(YX)$